# how to make current day selected from datetimepicker : angular js

Tags: angularjs

I have added a datetimepicker using angular js(1+) datetimepicker scripts.And write a line of code like this.

```
<input type='text' class="form-control" ng-model="submitAdsFormData.start_date" datetime-picker/>
```

And it's working properly.Now i want that only current date and next date should be selected from this datetimepicker rather than the previous date.

How can i do it?Can anyone help me to get this.thanks in advance.

Comment: please specify which library you are using for this.

Comment: angular-js/datetimepicker

Comment: @dev_02 what about `future-only` attribute?

Comment: future-only not working for me...